# R - List manipulation element concatenation

Tags: r, purrr

Assume I have a `list` with 5 elements:

```
list <- list("A", "B", "C", "D", c("E", "F"))
```

I am trying to return this to a simple character vector using `purrr` with the need to combine list elements that have two strings into one, separated by a delimiter such as '-'.  The output should look like this:

```
chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E-F"
```

I've tried a ton of approaches including paste, paste0, str_c and where I am getting hung up is it seems that map applies the function to each individual string of an element of a list and not the group of strings of an element (when there are more than one).  The closes I've gotten is:

```
list2 <- unlist(map(list, str_flatten))
str(list2)
```

This returns:

```
chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" "EF"
```

where I need a hyphen between E and F:

```
chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E-F"
```

When I try to pass a function as a parenthetiinton to `str_flatten()`, such as `str_flatten(list, collapse = "-")`, it doesn't work.  The big problem is I can't figure out what string to pass as an argument in str_flatten to group two strings of a given element of a list.

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it. Try

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
unlist(map(lst, str_flatten, collapse = "-"))
#[1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "D"   "E-F"
```

You could also use `map_chr`

```
map_chr(lst, str_flatten, collapse = "-")
```

---

Without additional packages and with thanks to @G.Grothendieck you could do

```
sapply(lst, paste, collapse = "-")
```

**data**

```
lst <- list("A", "B", "C", "D", c("E", "F"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `map_chr` and `paste`.

```
library(purrr)

lst <- list("A", "B", "C", "D", c("E", "F"))

map_chr(lst, ~paste(.x, collapse = "-"))
# [1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "D"   "E-F"
```